# Is it possible to modify the '/bin/su' command so that it will allow root access without password and without checking command ownership?

Tags: linux, permissions, sudo, root, su

I don't know well how the `su` command works. I know that `sudo` command must be owned by root for it to work.
Is it possible to modify the `su` command so that it runs the root shell without asking for the password, even if the executable is not owned by root?

Comment: You will need to [play with the sudoers file](https://www.google.com/search?q=sudoers+file+nopasswd).  ONLY DO SO USING THE `visudo` command.  If you don't do it via this command and you screw up, you are absolutely going to have a bad day.

Comment: Why would anyone even want to do this?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas `su` doesn't use the `sudoers` file

Comment: Yes @roaima I am aware of this.. it seems as if what the poster is asking for can be rectified with sudo.. perhaps I am misreading something.  I like your answer below nonetheless. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `su` utility requires root ownership to confer its privileges (by means of the setuid bit). If the utility is not owned by root it will not be possible for it to grant you root access.

```
ls -l /bin/su
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 50648 Jan 10  2019 /bin/su
```

Notice the `s` letter in the permissions where the user's `x` bit would normally be shown. This indicates the utility will run with the permissions associated with the owner.